# Image of a vector through a linear map given by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the matrix $
>      M = \begin{bmatrix} 
>     1&-2 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 4 & 1 \\ -1&1 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$ and the vector $v = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\  1 \\  2  \\ 2
>  \end{bmatrix}$.
>
> Describe the image of $v$ under the linear transformation associated with $M$.

The map is $f:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $f(x,y,z,t) = (x-2y+2z, 2x+4z+t, -x+y+t)$. Is it asking for $u \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f(v) = u $? If so, how do you find it? We haven't defined matrix multiplication yet, but I'd be happy to learn how to multiply a matrix by a vector. I looked at the wikipedia article on this, but it only talks about multiplying a matrix by a row vector, but $v$ is a column vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to evaluate $f(1,1,2,2)$ according to the rule that you have stated  $$f(x,y,z,t) = (x-2y+2z, 2x+4z+t, -x+y+t)^T.$$

Remark: Yes, after you have learn about matrix multiplication, the result is indeed just $M\cdot v$.

Comment: Oh, wow. Right under my nose. Thanks.